# Do we have a common expression to say that a person is in a rush and carelessly bumps into things or people?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms

A man is in a rush and bumps into a woman. In Vietnamese, that woman might get upset and say "*Where are your eyes and nose that you run like a thief*" (literally translated from Vietnamese).

**Do we have a common expression in English that express a similar idea?**

Comment: I common response to be rude like the lady in your example would be "watch where you're going!" As far as a word for "rushing and bumping into people" I cannot think of one, but we can say "in a hurry" to mean they are rushing and "clumsy" to mean they exhibit awkward behavior such as bumping into people.

Comment: [correction: [...] that express**es** a similar idea]

Comment: We have the phrase, *Running around like a chicken with its head cut off.*  It probably is the closest thing to a phrase that expresses the idea of frantically running around and bumping into things.  Although the expression sounds a bit brutal, it is quite common, generally inoffensive, and will be well understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Oy!" or "'Ere!" (meaning 'Here!') followed by "Look where you're going!", "Watch where you're going!", "Are you blind?!" or "Where's the fire?!" are all popular in the UK, perhaps with a final insult: "Clumsy oaf!" (There is a wide range of alternatives  to 'oaf', some of them even stronger.)

I myself shall be using the *Vietnamese* expression from now on.

Comment: Upvoted just for "I myself shall be using the Vietnamese expression from now on."

Comment: Also this is the most BrE post I have seen in my short time on this site.

Comment: What about "What's the hurry?" or "Why's the hurry?"?

Comment: @EliHarold Oy is typically BrE but Watch where you are going is not.

Comment: @Lambie yes I know. Oy, ere, where's the fire, and clumsy oaf all 4 are phrases I have not heard. "Watch where your going" is the one I suggested in the comments before this answer. I know it is not specifically British.

Comment: In my part of the U.S. *Oy* is what we assume Australians say.  So if you say *Oy* to me it will have no other meaning than to indicate you are an Aussie, regardless of where you may actually be from.  *Ere*, by the way, is something Hagrid might say.  Saying *Ere* will only indicate you are a Potter fan.

Answer (score 1):

We might say that this person is like [**a bull in a china shop**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/like-a-bull-in-a-china-shop).

It's not a perfect match, because "bull in a china shop" is more about carelessness than being in a hurry, but someone who behaves like this crashes around and causes damage.

Comment: "A bull in a china shop" usually means uncontrollable, reckless, and damaging. It somewhat fits here in the realm of insults.

Answer (score 0):

Presupposing you're not referring to words like "clumsy" or "oafish" (since you did indicate that the subject was in a hurry) I would suggest "[blundering](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blundering)", "[lumbering](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lumbering)" or "[bumbling](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bumbling)". Possibly "[pressed](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/press)", "[breakneck](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/breakneck)" or "[madcap](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/madcap)" are viable as well.